# How do I enumerate all the defined variables in a groovy script

Tags: groovy, scripting

I have a groovy script with an unknown number of variables in context at runtime, how do I find them all and print the name and value of each?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, if you're using a simple script (where you don't use the "def" keyword), the variables you define will be stored in the binding and you can get at them like this:

```
foo = "abc"
bar = "def"

if (true) {
    baz = "ghi"
    this.binding.variables.each {k,v -> println "$k = $v"}
}
```

Prints:

```
    foo = abc 
    baz = ghi 
    args = {} 
    bar = def
```

I'm not aware of an easy way to enumerate through the variables defined with the "def" keyword, but I'll be watching this question with interest to see if someone else knows how.

Comment: `this.binding.variables.each {k,v -> println "${v.class} $k = $v"}` If you want to see the types too

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Ted's answer will also work for 'def'ed variables.

```
def foo = "abc"
def bar = "def"

if (true) {
    baz = "ghi"
    this.binding.variables.each {k,v -> println "$k = $v"}
}
```

yields

```
baz = ghi
__ = [null, null, null]
foo = abc
_ = null
bar = def
```

I'm not sure what the _-variables signify, but I'm sure you can work around them.

Comment: `_` is the result of the last evaluated expression, at least in groovysh (and in Python's REPL and a number of others). Not sure about `__`, though I could see it being some other sort of evaluation history.

Comment: So, this doesn't work for me. `def foo = "asdgasgf"; this.binding.variables.each { k, v -> println "$k $v"}` only prints out `args []`.

Answer (score 0):

Groovy Object contains method - `dump()`
https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html

```
String  dump()
Generates a detailed dump string of an object showing its class, hashCode and fields.
```

Example:

```
class MyClass {
    def foo = "abc"
    def bar = "def"
}


println(new MyClass().dump())
```

stdout: `<MyClass@1fa268de foo=abc bar=def>`