# How to get all Groovy variables with the last values using reflection

Tags: reflection, groovy

I would like in my groovy script to dump all variables and display all values.

I would like to do it dynamically because I would like to surround all my huge groovies by a *try/catch*. In *catch* part I want to dump all variables state with the stacktrace. The code should be generic to all groovies.

The problem is that *this.getBinding().getVariables()* doesn't return the correct variable state.

I've made a small script to illustrate the situation:

```
def test1 = 1;
test1 = 2;

int test2 = 1;
test2 = 2;

test3 = 1;
test3 = 2;

def errLog=new File("c:/temp/groovy_debug.txt");   
errLog.append("--------------------------------------------------------" + "\n");
errLog.append("  Context ["+getBinding().getVariables()+" ] \n");
errLog.append("--------" + "\n") ;
```

after the execution I get a very strange result

```
--------------------------------------------------------
  Context [[[creationStackTrace= <not available>], test1:null, errLog:null, test2:null, test3:2] ] 
--------
```

it means that the declared variables are always reported as null or as first assignment, but for not typed variables it get the last value.
I would like to get the last situation for all variables (value=2).

Is it possible to get them?

Comment: My result (in temp file) is different: --------------------------------------------------------
  Context [[_outputTransforms:[groovy.ui.OutputTransforms$_loadOutputTransforms_closure1@27a97cea, groovy.ui.OutputTransforms$_loadOutputTransforms_closure2@5d4803d2, groovy.ui.OutputTransforms$_loadOutputTransforms_closure3@7f10fc0a, groovy.ui.OutputTransforms$_loadOutputTransforms_closure4@517b5471, groovy.ui.OutputTransforms$_loadOutputTransforms_closure5@3dd93c98], _:null, __:[], args:[], test3:2] ] 
--------
Is this complete code, or part of bigger project?

Comment: (limtt of length) my result is from Groovy Console. Do You remember, that groovy "script" is hidden implementation of "run()" in Script class ?

Comment: This is the full script but it's evaluated inside another software. When I tried to list all methods using 
this.getClass().getMethods()
I see plenty of methods.

Comment: these are method "in Java way", every officjal groovy object/class has many. Your question, if I  understand, is about local variables (????). Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216484/how-do-i-enumerate-all-the-defined-variables-in-a-groovy-script

Comment: I want to get all variables: local, global, static, def'ined or not

Comment: I can confirm, strange. My groovy console show only test3 (variable not def'ined in any form)

Comment: As (quite) old programmer, I must understand,. You give me strong homework  :) Say "in myown words", not defined variables are "in interpreter way", defined "in compiled way" Read answer by Ted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184002/groovy-whats-the-purpose-of-def-in-def-x-0?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Tiny observation: using Groovy from Java in more "object way" i.e. compile full class (not script)  from GroovyClassLoader using un-defined variables is more restricted (gives evident error). I made short investigation, Binding context seems specific to script mode

Answer (score 0):

Tim Yates' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15619906/160256) illustrates why you're having difficulty accessing the non-global variables.  For simple cases like yours, where you just have assignments and declarations, you can use a visitor to collect the results, like this

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.*
import java.security.CodeSource

def scriptText = '''
def test1 = 1;
test1 = 2;

int test2 = 1;
test2 = 2;

test3 = 1;
test3 = 2;
'''

class VariableVisitor extends ClassCodeVisitorSupport {
    def vars = [:]
    void visitExpressionStatement(ExpressionStatement statement) {
        if (statement.expression instanceof BinaryExpression)
            vars.put(statement.expression.leftExpression.name, statement.expression.rightExpression.value)
        super.visitExpressionStatement(statement)
    }
    void visitReturnStatement(ReturnStatement statement) {
        if (statement.expression instanceof BinaryExpression)
            vars.put(statement.expression.leftExpression.name, statement.expression.rightExpression.value)
        super.visitReturnStatement(statement)
    }
    protected SourceUnit getSourceUnit() {
        return source;
    }
}
class CustomSourceOperation extends CompilationUnit.PrimaryClassNodeOperation {
    CodeVisitorSupport visitor
    void call(SourceUnit source, GeneratorContext context, ClassNode classNode) throws CompilationFailedException {
        classNode.visitContents(visitor)
    }
}
class MyClassLoader extends GroovyClassLoader {
    CodeVisitorSupport visitor
    protected CompilationUnit createCompilationUnit(CompilerConfiguration config, CodeSource source) {
        CompilationUnit cu = super.createCompilationUnit(config, source)
        cu.addPhaseOperation(new CustomSourceOperation(visitor: visitor), Phases.CLASS_GENERATION)
        return cu
    }
}

def visitor =  new VariableVisitor()
def myCL = new MyClassLoader(visitor: visitor)
def script = myCL.parseClass(scriptText)

assert visitor.vars == ["test1":2, "test2":2, "test3":2]
```

However, if your script has more complicated stuff going on (like conditional assignments), you'll need something more sophisticated.  You'd need to actually run the script and collect the results.